# How to view HEIC files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed the HEVC extension on Windows 11 and I can view HEIC files using Windows Photos app.

But in VS code I still get:

> The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or
> uses an unsupported text encoding.

It also pops up a window that shows me:

> Configure default editor for '*.heic'...

How can I either configure another editor that supports viewing HEIC files (like Windows Photos), or just make VSCode use the codec itself?

Thanks